# Stock quotes API?

Tags: api, wordpress

I'm trying to put together a simple RSS widget (for my wordpress blog) that will show a list of stocks, or markets, and their current prices.

I cant seem to find an API for this data anywhere - can anyone suggest such a thing (perhaps as an RSS feed?)

Comment: How is this not programming related? It's *directly* related to writing PHP, and is just asking about an API for stock quotes..

Comment: Definitely programming related and very useful question

Comment: Sure it is. There is so blinded people ...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yahoo have an (undocumented) Stock Quotes API as part of their [Finance API](http://developer.yahoo.com/finance/)

Basically, http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GOOG&f=ll will return the price for `GOOG` stock in CVS format

The `s` parameter is the stock symbol. You can specify multiple by separating them with `+`

```
quotes.csv?s=GOOG+YHOO‎
```

The `f` parameter is the data format code, which I found documented from [this Python script](http://www.goldb.org/ystockquote.html) (which is also how I discovered the API..):

```
code   description

l1     price
c1     change
v      volume
a2     avg_daily_volume
x      stock_exchange
j1     market_cap
b4     book_value
j4     ebitda
d      dividend_per_share
y      dividend_yield
e      earnings_per_share
k      52_week_high
j      52_week_low
m3     50day_moving_avg
m4     200day_moving_avg
r      price_earnings_ratio
r5     price_earnings_growth_ratio
p5     price_sales_ratio
p6     price_book_ratio
s7     short_ratio
```

They are all documented on [this page](http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm)

The data is returned as a comma separated file, which should be utterly trivial to parse in any language

You can also use Google's Finance API to get Stock Quotes in a slightly round-a-bout way

Basically you create a Google Spreadsheet, and use the [GoogleFinance function](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=54198):

```
=GoogleFinance("GOOG"; "price")
```

..then use the Spreadsheet API to access that value

I found this via ["Introducing the Google Finance API"](http://googlified.com/introducing-the-google-finance-api/
), and ["How to get a real-time stock quote using Google API"](http://yken.org/2009/01/05/how-to-get-a-real-time-stock-quote-using-google-api/) describes this is more detail, including a simple bash shell-script to access the data (I think it could be simplified by making the spreadsheet publicly accessible)

Comment: This roundabout way might be a bit difficult to use if you want to locate any stock.

Comment: This API has been discontinued:
"It has come to our attention that this service is being used in violation of the Yahoo Terms of Service. As such, the service is being discontinued. For all future markets and equities data research, please refer to finance.yahoo.com."

Answer (score 6):

There are already a few Wordpress plugins; among others:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stock-quote-sidebar/

http://andy.hillhome.org/blog/code/stockquotesidebar/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stocks-watchlist/

Comment: And why the mysterious downvote of this answer 6 months later? The question is tagged Wordpress.